# My ubuntu says I should upgrade but then doesn't let me

Tags: upgrade, updates, 21.04, do-release-upgrade

I seem to have run into a workflow bug, with end of lifecycle with Ubuntu. I am getting the screenshot below. So I hit Upgrade... to upgrade it and then nothing happens.

[image: Software Updater message: Software updates are no longer provided for Ubuntu 21.04. To stay secure, you should upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10]

So then I hit Upgrade... and nothing happens.

I googled and saw that I should run enter `do-release-upgrade` only to realize that that's basically running the same thing.

```
christopherwork@Chris-Gaming-Linux:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

It sounds like when I click Upgrade... it's actually running do-release-upgrade and then silently exiting? Either way this is super annoying, and seems like an obvious bug to fix.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: A number of packages were in the -proposed repository sitting waiting their 7 days before getting into -updates.. however the EOL beat them... this was an *unexpected* issue (*fixes should not be uploaded if its within 7 days of EOL to avoid this*) creating issues that will ideally be unique to 21.04 (*uploader was spoken to & reminded!*).  Your issue is you should have *release-upgraded* before EOL and you'd have got the fixes at 21.10 before the EOL date was reached and not had this issue.

Comment: You will need to reinstall fresh this time. If you prefer to upgrade, always remember to do that *before* your current version is EOL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an obvious error comes an obvious fix. One of my packages was held back during apt upgrade

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libc++1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

And apt dist-upgrade was not upgrading either.

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libc++1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

It had to be upgraded by installing it.

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt install libc++1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc++1-12 libc++abi1-12
Suggested packages:
  clang
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libc++1-11 libc++abi1-11
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc++1-12 libc++abi1-12
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc++1
1 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 264 kB of archives.
After this operation, 25.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

After that do-release-upgrade worked.

Comment: For future releases, remember that the EOL date also marks the end of the supported upgrade path to the next release.  It's expected that you upgrade *before* the release becomes EOL, not after.  Standard releases come out every six months and are supported for nine months, so you only get three months to upgrade. The cadence for LTS releases is much more forgiving. LTS releases come out every two years and are supported for five years.

Comment: A number of packages were in the -proposed repository sitting waiting their 7 days before getting into -updates.. however the EOL beat them... this was an *unexpected* issue (*fixes should not be uploaded if its within 7 days of EOL to avoid this*) creating issues that will ideally be unique to 21.04 (*uploader was spoken to & reminded!*).  Your issue is you should have *release-upgraded* before EOL and you'd have got the fixes at 21.10 before the EOL date was reached and not had this issue.

Comment: FYI:   Well done for solving it; but I still the issue you had as a user-created issue, because you missed the EOL (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/) and the issue you encountered was purely as a result of that  (*issue contributed by fixes being uploaded too late for hirsute yes, thus complicating users who didn't upgrade on time as intended*)

Comment: FYI, in these cases, `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` will automatically take care of things - the 'held back' is because it has NEW packages that it has to install to fulfill dependencies, which requires dist-upgrade or full-upgrade arguments to actually install ALL the deps.  `dist-upgrade` does not upgrade your distribution contrary to what the world believes either, it's basically full upgrade

Answer (score -2):

**Try these commands:**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt list --upgradable
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean -y
```

Comment: How does installing `libc++1` and cleaning up help the OP?